# Why cant I type numbers in the Terminal window?

Tags: rar

I recently installed Xubuntu...and it runs great...until I tried to install software using the Terminal window.  Specifically...$ sudo apt-get install unrar.  I downloaded .rar files and needed something to open them. After pressing enter, it then asked for my password which contains numbers.  YES!!! the numlock was on. lol  I couldnt type my password.  No numbers came up.

Answer (score 1):

The numlock key on an external keyboard may not control the "embedded" keypad on laptop  keyboards without a keypad (the jkl=123 mapping etc.). You can always use the number keys above the qwerty row.